# Testing whether population is homogeneous or not

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

Before starting let me mention that I am not completely sure the title represents what I am searching for (this is in part why I am asking the question).

I have a small number of elements (let's say less than 20). Each of these elements "fails" every once in a while. When considered globally, the total number of failures is higher than I expected. I am trying to find out why. First I would like to rule out that the reason for this higher number of failures is due to some "bad" apples.

When looking at the number of failures per each element it looks like they are all failing at similar rates. Is there a way to formally test this?.

More concretely, consider I have 5 elements and that the observed number of failures by element in the period (which length I know) is 3, 4, 5, 3 and 7.

Then, How can I test whether the failure distributions of each element are the same or maybe how to test if there is an element that is behaving different (i.e. a different failure distribution from the rest). In the example above it looks like 7 might be a high number but how to formally test this?

If you can point me in the right direction (just some  keywords would be enough) I will continue by myself.

I have searched some but I don't think I am using the right keywords. I am not sure if a $\chi^{2}$ test would be applicable in this case or not.

Comment: If you are still interested, consider make the post more concrete, we like more specific information. But search for *hazard* or *failure rate*, *survival*